# Realm objects returns nil after adding

Tags: swift, realm, realm-cloud

I created an Person object when the User logs in:

```
let creds = SyncCredentials.jwt(accessToken)
SyncUser.logIn(with: creds, server: Constants.syncAuthURL, onCompletion: { [weak self](user, err) in
    if let user = user {
        self?.setDefaultRealmConfiguration(with: user)
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let identity = (user.identity)!

        let person = Person()
        person.id = identity
        try! realm.write {
          realm.add(person, update: true)
        }

        self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showProfile", sender: self)
     }                    
})
```

The Person successfully created on the cloud server.

In the next viewcontroller i like to fetch the object based on the id:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
guard let uuid = SyncUser.current?.identity! else { return }
let person = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("id = %@", uuid).first

try! realm.write {
  person?.name = "test"
}
```

The person is always nil I also tried the query the object with the primary key, but with no success.

The Person class looks like:

```
class Person : Object {

    @objc dynamic var id = ""
    @objc dynamic var created: Date = Date()
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var email = ""
    @objc dynamic var avatar : Data?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I created a new app with just one Viewcontroller and the Person class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let creds = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: "admin", password: "test")
    SyncUser.logIn(with: creds, server: Constants.AUTH_URL, onCompletion: { (user, err) in
        if let user = user {

            var config = user.configuration(realmURL: Constants.REALM_URL)
            config.objectTypes = [Person.self]
            Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: config, callback: { (realm, error) in

                guard let realm = realm else {return}

                let objects = realm.objects(Person.self)

                print(objects) // always empty why???

                try! realm.write {
                    let p = Person()
                    p.id = "test"
                    realm.add(p)
                }
                print(objects) // one object
            })
        }
    })
  }
}
```

as with my other problem the person is successfully added to the cloud. but when I restart the app the objects are empty on the first query. Maybe I miss understanding something with the synched realms?

Comment: SyncUser.current?.identity! will give you an optional string.. something like  Optional("uuid"). Try SyncUser.current!.identity! instead. However it will be better if you use a guard for the uuid.

Comment: I added the guard for the uuid, object is still nil. I also tried to set the id to a fixed string and query that. but even then the results are empty.

Comment: oh, if you remove the objects filter, is the user object you are looking for within the objects found?

Comment: no the result is empty

Comment: seems like the Person object is not added to realm, or added to another realm file.

Comment: but the object appears on the realm studio after I added it

Comment: try calling self?.setDefaultRealmConfiguration(with: user) before you init the realm for retrieving Person object.

Comment: still same (nil or empty) results.

Comment: I added a second example maybe this makes my question clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let results = realm.objects(Person.self)
let subscription = results.subscribe()
print(results)
```

resolve my problem